# How to select a div in an asp.net repeater

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a div inside an asp.net repeater. I would like to handle an event on the client side when a user clicks on one of the div's.

I've tried the onClick handler in the div (class="result"), but that doesn't seem to be firing. Is there another event I can tie this too?

I also try creating an event handler using jquery, but I'm not sure how to select the element that the user clicks. Right now, I seem to be tying the event to all the div's. Any idea how I can fix the jquery selector for the a single div element?

My repeater:

```
<div id="search-results" >
    <asp:Repeater ID="pageResults" runat="server" ItemType="ArchiveViewer.Logic.PageResult" 
        SelectMethod="GetSearchResults" OnItemDataBound="pageResults_ItemDataBound" >
             <ItemTemplate> 
                <div class="result" data-pageid="<%#:Item.PageId %>" data-pageNumber="<%#:Item.Number %>"
                    onclick="resultSelected"  >
                        <div>
                            Page: <%#:Item.Number %>
                        </div>  
                        <div>
                          <asp:Label ID="lblSearchResult" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>                                        
                 </div>
             </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

And my jquery scripts:

```
$('#search-results div').click(function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        // this is setting the active class for all the div's in the repeater...
});

var resultSelected = function () {
        // this is not working
};
```

**EDIT:**

I'm no longer using the onclick event in the div. My jquery code looks like:

To add the .active class:

```
        $('#search-results div.result').click(function (e) {
            var pageNumber = ($(this).attr('data-pageNumber'));

            if (pageNumber != null) {
                $("#search-results div").removeClass('active');             
                $(this).addClass('active');
                getHighlightResults(pageNumber);
            }
        });

       var getHighlightResults = function (pagenumber) {
           // Do some stuff
           // Some function where I trigger the event on the active class
           $('div.result.active').trigger('first-click');           
        };
```

The following is not being triggered. Is it because my selector is incorrect?

```
$('div.result.active').bind('first-click', function (e) {
            var pageNumber = ($(this).attr('data-pageNumber'));
            alert("in bind: " + pageNumber);
            if (pageNumber != null) {
                var dv = $('#diva-viewer').data('diva');                
                dv.gotoPageByNumber(pageNumber);
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
});
```

Comment: When the user clicks the div, I call a function to get some data, update a third party plug in, the trigger the event on the active div. I cannot get the last event to trigger if I specify it for the `active` div. it works on all results though. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first jQuery script actually looks OK... except all it will ever do is apply the class `active` to a div. So when you click a 2nd div, now you have two divs with class `active`, and a 3rd you have three, etc...

What you want to do is clear out all the other `active` classes when you click:

```
$('#search-results div').click(function (e) {
    $('#search-results div').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This would be essentially the same as if you just applied a click event to all the `divs` with `class="result"`. You'll be better off removing the inline `onclick` that you have in your repeater `divs`. Then you can call subsequent functions like:

```
$('#search-results div.result').on('click', function () {
    var pageNumber = ($(this).attr('data-pageNumber'));
    console.log('Fetched ' + pageNumber);
    if (pageNumber != null) {
        $('#search-results div.result').each(function () { 
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });

        //add the active class and click handler
        $(this).addClass('active');
        getHighlightResults(pageNumber); //call getHighlightResults with pageNumber
        activeDivAction(this); // call activeDivAction passing the div that was clicked
    }
});

var getHighlightResults = function (pageNumber) {
    // Do some stuff
    console.log('inside getHighlightResults for ' + pageNumber); 
};

var activeDivAction = function(activeDiv) {
   var pageNumber = ($(activeDiv).attr('data-pageNumber'));
   console.log('inside activeDivAction for ' + pageNumber);
};
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PE48f/3/)

Comment: I know I don't need them both, but since neither was working, I was trying to figure out what did. ;) So, if I wanted to had a handler to the click event for the "active" result (after I've made it , would I do it like this: `$('.result active').bind('first-click', function (e) {...` because that is not working...

Comment: @Tums updated answer, and added a fiddle, on how to bind and unbind events just for the active divs, if that is what you are trying to do

Comment: The unbinding on a click event isn't exactly what I want to do. I don't want the user to have to double click. I have an event being triggered that I only want to run on the .active div's after the user clicks on them. Is that possible without unbinding?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. When they click on a div, it becomes active and you can run whatever function you want. Both answers show having only one active div at a time. Is that NOT what you want? Do you want that any amount of divs can be clicked and then turned active and everytime they click a div, you run a function on all active divs?

Comment: I've updated my question so that it is (hopefully) more clear.

Comment: @Tums it's not any more clear to me, sorry. If they click a div, just run the functions you need. No reason to try to trigger a click event for a div.... they just clicked. You already know what they clicked, so run logic.

Comment: Commented above before I saw this. I need to pass data to a third party control and then trigger that last function. Doing it another way was causing a number of issues with the third party plug in. That's why I did this way. But if you know something better, please tell me. I new to jquery so I may be missing something basic.

Comment: @Tums updated answer and fiddle again. I think that is what you want. Just call the final function and pass it the div that was clicked.

Comment: I have an ajax call in that highlight function. So it does: 1. click event, 2. activediv, 3. highlight, instead of 2. highlight, 3. activediv...

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid...I re-worked the last function call and put it in the ajax success function. Thank you for working through this with me. I was focusing on the wrong problem. I also found out that you can set ajax to be synchronous, but I didn't try that. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to change to make this work.  Your repeater produces html similar to this:

```
<div id="search-results">
    <div class="result" onclick="resultSelected();">
        <div>result</div>
        <div>some label</div>
    </div>
    <div class="result" onclick="resultSelected();">
        <div>result</div>
        <div>some label</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to remove the active class on all divs, but only add it to the clicked div:

```
$("#search-results div.result").click(function(){
    $("div").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

resultSelected = function(){
    console.log("clicked, but don't really need this...");
}
```

If you wanted to add the onclick handler to the html you need to change it to be calling a function via () at the end of the name.  You also need to change the script to declare the function without defining it as a var.  There is no reason to do this though if you are using jQuery.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/_iii_/2kW8T/)

Comment: Thank for the info about the var. That did indeed help.

Comment: The click event is getting bound to the elements specified by the selector.  It only fires for the div that you click. The active class is only being added to the outer result div that you click.

Comment: What is the outer result?

Comment: you have div's inside the div with class result.  your original code had a selector only down to div and not div.result.  so the event handler was actually getting bound to div.result and the divs inside of it.  that is probably also why you would have been getting odd results.